# _label attribute used on anchor tags (HTML)

Tags: html, xhtml

I recently came across a html email that contained _label attributes on the < a > tags? I've never seen this before and have searched all over the web but can't find out whether they are legit attributes.

The weird thing is in Internet Explorer they appear as a title attribute would (appearing on mouseover) but don't in any other browser.

Example of use:

```
<a href="#" _label="this is the label">Click here</a>
```

Does anyone have any idea whether it's something just Internet Explorer was going to introduce? Or someone at a big company has made a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never seen that used before. The [`a` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2) does not have a `_label` or `label` attribute, so it's invalid HTML.

However, it *is* valid to start an attribute name with an underscore (assuming you're using XML/XHTML), so perhaps it's used by some script to produce the tooltip you mentioned. I don't have IE to hand to check if it always happens.

Comment: On IE 9, I cannot see any mouseover effect when using `_label`. Perhaps the effect was observed on a page that uses JavaScript to do something with such attributes, in a manner that works on IE but not on other browsers.
If that is the case, the usage is not recommendable. For “custom” attributes, it is better to use names that start with `data-` (e.g., `data-label`), as recommended in HTML5 drafts.

Comment: Think I confused the question a bit. It doesn't show as a tooltip, it's just the browser using the attribute as if it was a title tag. There's no javascript because this was used in a html email. It's really random! It was used on this email http://www.inboxvision.com/email-gallery/getmessage.php?msg=MQ494F055ADBA6E1D

Comment: Very strange. I've never seen it before. I can't reproduce it in IE9 , or IE9 in 8 or 7 mode. What browser did you notice it in? On a side note, that document is completely and utterly invalid: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.inboxvision.com%2Femail-gallery%2Fgetmessage.php%3Fmsg%3DMQ494F055ADBA6E1D&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: haha yer it's quite bad considering it's a big company doing it! Oh well they must have a reason for doing it ... just thought I was missing something ... but obviously not!

Comment: What browser did you notice it in originally? I'm still trying to reproduce it but failing in all browsers.

Comment: I think it was in IE7 (was on a work pc) will try and get a screenshot tomorrow. It looked like it was basically using them as title tags. That's why I though perhaps it was an old IE/Word tag or something.

Comment: they show in IE7 and below when using ie7 tester http://www.flickr.com/photos/73658709@N02/6643245999/

Comment: Intriguing. I think it must be some old IE thing that has no real use. It's invalid HTML so I would suggest never using it (not that there would be any reason to!).

Comment: I wouldn't use it either ... didn't even know it existed ... very strange that Debenhams are using it that's all. Cheers for the help! :)